# MySQL 5.6.6-m9 32-bit fails to compile on 64-bit Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, makefile, cmake

I'm compiling 32-bit MySQL 5.6.6-m9 with CMake on my multilib CLFS machine. 64-bit compiles without issue, but 32-bit fails:

```
/sources/mysql-5.6.6-m9/mysys/lf_alloc-pin.c: In function 'lf_pinbox_init':
/sources/mysql-5.6.6-m9/mysys/lf_alloc-pin.c:118:3: error: size of array 'compile_time_assert' is negative
```

Line 118 of lf_alloc-pin.c is:

```
compile_time_assert(sizeof(LF_PINS) == 64);
```

What causes this to fail is adding -m32 to the CXX and CPP flags. If I remove -m32, it compiles fine, but compiles the 64-bit libraries. I need the 32-bit libraries.

Is there any way to fix this? Would removing the compile_time_assert line from the C file be bad?

Comment: Removing the assert would probably be bad. Just manually changing the compiler flags is probably also bad. There should be some sort of "build in 32bit mode" flag for the configure script.

Comment: This is the first source tarball I've tried to compile with CMake, so if there is some sort of easy and simple 32-bit flag, I have no idea what it is or where to find it.